# Linking MKL library in C++

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I'm having a lot of trouble linking the Intel MKL libraries to my code in C++. I downloaded the MKL library from this link:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/math-kernel-library/choose-download/windows.html

Then it says to use MKL Link Line Advisor to obtain the proper compiler options, which I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out. For reference, I'm using Windows, g++ 8.1.0 and MinGW-W64. Here is part by part:

- Intel product: Intel MKL 2020, since I just downloaded it.
- OS: Windows, no issues there.
- Compiler: Intel(R) Fortran? I'm using g++ to compile my C++ code, so
  I have no idea since that option is not available. Doing some
  research in stackoverflow, it seems the right choice is Intel(R)
  Fortran
- Architecture: Intel(R) 64, since I have a 64-bit OS?
- Dynamic/Static Linking: Static linking I guess?
- Interface layer: 64-bit, since I have a 64-bit OS?
- Threading layer: OpenMP, since my current C++ code uses -fopenmp?
- OpenMP library: Intel(R) libiomp5. Only one option, so no issues
  here.
- Fortran95 Interfaces: BLAS95 and LAPACK95

The above choices give me the following compiler options

```
 /4I8 /module:"%MKLROOT%"\include\intel64/ilp64 -I"%MKLROOT%"\include
```

And this results in error from the compiler:

```
/4I8: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I once tried to link against MKL under MinGW and failed with many "undefined symbol"s during the linkage. Nevertheless, try to select Linux and then GNU C/C++ compiler. Note that command options under MinGW (and Linux) are specified with `-` and not `/`. You can use both 64-bit and 32-bit interface layer in 64-bit applications. If you use 64-bit interface, you should add `-DMKL_ILP64` compiler option (analogous to `/4I8`, which is purely Fortran option), linking with 64-bits libraries without defining `MKL_ILP64` will give you a segfault upon execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use -DMKL_ILP64 -I"%MKLROOT%"\include for g++.
You should definitely not pick Intel(R) Fortran for the compiler since you are not compiling Fortran programs.

Comment: here is the link to the intel mkl linker adviser: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html